# Hierarchical clustering with specific number of data in each cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm clustering a set of words using "Hierarchical Clustering". I want each cluster to contain a certain number of words, for example 2 words, or 3 words.

I'm trying to modify [existing code](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/hierarchical-clustering-single-linkage-algorithm) for this clustering.

I just put the value of max(d) to Inf as well

```r
 Lm[min(d),] <- sl
 Lm[,min(d)] <- sl
 if (length(cluster)>2){#if it's already clustered with more than 2 points
                     #then dont't cluster them again by setting values to Inf
      Lm[min(d), min(d)] <- Inf
      Lm[max(d), max(d)] <- Inf

      Lm[max(d),] <- Inf
      Lm[,max(d)] <- Inf
      Lm[min(d),] <- Inf
      Lm[,min(d)] <- Inf
  }
```

However, it doesn't give me the expected results, I was wondering if it's correct approach? How can I do this type of clustering with constraint in r ?

example of results that I got

```
row  V1  V2
166 -194   -38
167 166 -1
……..
240 239 239
241 240 240
242 241 241
243 242 242
244 243 243
```

Comment: I don't think you can have this constraint with hierarchical clustering. You could try partitional clustering with something like k-means, where you can specify how many clusters you want, which you could set to a value that would roughly give you the desired number of elements per cluster. BTW, link's broken (extra `>` at the end).

Comment: @Alexis the problem is that I don't know the number of clusters. The link is fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will be tough to optimize, or it can produce arbitrarily bad results. Because your size constraint goes against the principles of clustering.

Consider the one-dimensional data set -100, -1, 1, 100. Assuming you want to limit the cluster size to 2 elements. Hierarchical clustering will first merge -1 and +1 because they are closest. Now they have reached maximum size, so the only option is now to cluster -100 and +100, the worst possible result - this cluster is as big as the entire data set.

Comment: Is this issue for Agglomerative or it's the same with Divisive as well? I mean if I try Divisive would I face with this issue?

Comment: Divisive will face very similar issues. Which of the 2^N splits you do first will turn out to be optimal later?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an example of what I meant with partitional clustering:

```
library(cluster)
data("ruspini")

desired_cluster_size <- 3L
corresponding_num_clusters <- round(nrow(ruspini) / desired_cluster_size)

km <- kmeans(ruspini, corresponding_num_clusters)
table(km$cluster)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
 3  3  2  4  2  2  2  1  3  3  2  3  2  3  3  2  6  3  2  1  3  6  2  8  4
```

This definitely can't guarantee how many observations you'll have in each group,
and it's **not** deterministic,
but it at least gives you an approximation.
In the tabulated results you can see that many clusters (1 through 25) ended up with 2 or 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Kmeans before, but it didn't give me the desired results. Because my data are so close, so the results would be sth like this
`(1   2   3   4   5   6)
(1   2   1   5   1   2)
`
one cluster may take more than desired data points which shouldn't happen in my system.